# Mongoose .insertOne() not working (no error message given)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using node.js to code a simple login/ sign up program that stores the account details (username, email, and password) on a MongoDB database. I've made sure I've downloaded MongoDB correctly, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code... there are no errors thrown but the `name`, `email`, and `hashedPassword` aren't being inserted into the users database.

Here's my code from my server.js file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config()
  }
  
  const express = require('express')
  const app = express()
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
  const passport = require('passport')
  const flash = require('express-flash')
  const session = require('express-session')
  const methodOverride = require('method-override')

  const userArray = [];

  const mongoose = require('mongoose')
  mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  const db = mongoose.connection
  db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
  db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose'))
  
   const initializePassport = require('./passport-config')
  initializePassport(
    passport,
    email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
    id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
  )
  
  app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
  app.use(flash())
  app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  }))
  app.use(passport.initialize())
  app.use(passport.session())
  app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
  
  app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs', { name: req.user.name })
  })
  
  app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs')
  })
  
  app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
  }))
  
  app.get('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('register.ejs')
  })

//**THE PROBLEM IS SOMEWHERE HERE I THINK**
  app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Before try")
    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        console.log("Password hashed")
        userArray.push({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
          })
        console.log("pushed to array")
        db.users.insertOne({
            "name": req.body.name,
            "email": req.body.email,
            "password": hashedPassword
        })
        console.log("New user loaded to DB!")
        console.log(req.body.name);
        console.log(req.body.email);
        console.log(hashedPassword);
        res.redirect('/login')
      } catch {
        res.redirect('/register')
      }
  })
  
  
  app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut()
    res.redirect('/login')
  })
  
  function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next()
    }
  
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
  
  function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
  }
  
  app.listen(3000)
```

I'm having the issue on the `app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {}` part

I logged each step line of it and this is what comes up in the console:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Connected to Mongoose
Before try
Password hashed
pushed to array
```

So, as you can see, everything works except for inserting the user info into the database (I also know that because running db.users.find() in the Mongo shell returns nothing)... please help :'(

Comment: `db.users.insertOne` - this is not a common syntax Mongoose ODM documentation has - Mongoose uses a Schema and Model and related methods

Comment: But it says here (https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_insert.asp) that `.insertOne()` can be used in node.js to insert the data into the DB... What syntax should I use instead of `.insertOne()`?

Comment: That (the link) is _not_ referring to Mongoose APIs. It is the [MongoDB NodeJS Driver.](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax error when adding the user info to the users database. Instead of:

```
db.users.insertOne({
            "name": req.body.name,
            "email": req.body.email,
            "password": hashedPassword
        })
```

it should be:

```
db.collection("users").insertOne({
            "name": req.body.name,
            "email": req.body.email,
            "password": hashedPassword
        })
```